# How can i write this SQL query in CYPHER?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, neo4j, cypher

This the following SQL Query

```
select count(distinct Descendent_id) from
(
select * 
from v.ABC a
left join v.XYZ b
on a.Target_id=b.Ancestor_id
) t
where t.Target_id = 1234;
```

**Edit**

There's actually no relationship between the two tables / nodes. I'll explain -

Let's assume Table B has **Ancestor_Id** and **Descendent_id** which has some relationship between them we can call it [children]

> Ancestor_Id - 101 --[children]--> Descendent_Id - 101.1
>
> Ancestor_Id - 101 --[children]--> Descendent_Id - 101.2

---

Table A has only **Target_Id** which are the same as of Table B,
Eg - Table A - Target_Id = 101 | Table - B Ancestor_Id = 101

Note -

> Table A doesn't have any relationship with Table B.

So I need to join the two tables / nodes with **Target_Id and Ancestor_ID** and what ultimately i want is DISTINCT COUNT of *Descendent_Id* from Table B which has a [children] relationship with Ancestor_Id.

---

> Also from the SQL Query if you can see Descendent_id doesn't has any
> alias pre-pended to it like b.Descendent, how do I achieve the same in
> Neo4j.

---

Kindly let me know if I've still not cleared the doubt properly.

I am very new in CYPHER - Neo4j, KINDLY HELP!

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

The following Cypher will get the number of distinct `D_id` values in the "left join" of `abc` and `xyz` nodes having the specified ID.

```
MATCH (a:abc) WHERE a.id = $id
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:xyz) WHERE b.abc_id = $id
WITH COLLECT(a.D_id)+COLLECT(b.D_id) AS ids
UNWIND ids AS id
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS D_id_count
```

I assume that `abc` nodes store the ID in an `id` property, and `xyz` nodes store it in an `abc_id` property. I also assume that the desired ID value is passed as an `id` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

Note: this query would be faster if you created [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on:

- `:abc(id)`
- `:xyz(abc_id)`

Comment: There's actually no relationship between the two tables / nodes. I'll explain - 

Let's assume Table A has Id and name which has some relationship between them we can call it [AB]

Table B has only Id which are the same as of Table A,
Eg - Table A_Id = 101 | Table B_Id = 101. But there can be Table A_Id has 102 and B_Id doesn't.

So I need to join the two tables with Id and what ultimately i want is the *name* from Table A which has a [AB] relationship with A_Id. 

Kindly let me know if I've still not cleared the doubt properly.

Comment: What exactly is the D_id in the above query? Is the D_id some joined column? Do i need to join both the tables while loading data in Neo4j?

Comment: The query assumes that `D_id` is the name of a property that can exist in b oth `abc` and `xyz` nodes.